# Visual Studio 2022 -Crystal reports Application - Crystal Reports presents a blank report

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2022

I recently installed Visual Studio 2022 along with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (RforVS6413SP33_0-80007712)

I am able to preview data in the dataset but my report shows no data whatsoever.

Getting desperate/

It was supposed to be simple.

Any clue ?

I tried everything that I could think of, really ... Including making a test report with just one table (no joins or anything)

I am using Visual Studio for windows and it's a VB app.

Windows 10 Pro and SQL server Express.